# How can I add more directories to my file deletion program?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use this to delete all .htm files in certain in a couple of directories I have by using recursion. So far it works fine with just one folder, but I haven't been able to find a way to add more than one folder to the code. Is there any way i can add more directories to the directory path so I don't have to keep changing the code every time I want it to delete files in another directory?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Deleter
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string directorypath = @"C:\Public\";
            string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directorypath);
            DeleteDirectories(directories);
        }
        private static void DeleteDirectories(string[] directories)
        {
            foreach (string directory in directories)
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.htm");
                DeleteFiles(files);
                directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
                DeleteDirectories(directories);
            }
        }
        private static void DeleteFiles(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
                if (f.CreationTime < DateTime.Now)
                    f.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific question do you have?

Comment: "More directories" is a fairly meaningless thing without more context. What directories do you want to "add" to this?

Comment: can you add a little more detail about what you actually want to delete? Are you just trying to clear out all of your .htm files?

Comment: `Main(string[] args)` Ever wonder what the `args` bit is all about?

Comment: do you want to join directory arrays?

Comment: I'm trying to use this to delete all .htm files in certain in a couple of directories I have by using recursion. So far it works fine with just one folder, but I haven't been able to find a way to add more than one folder to the code. Is there any way i can add more directories to the directory path so I don't have to keep changing the code every time I want it to delete files in another directory?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting your enumerable (directories) to the sub directories & hoping to recurse that way, create a new reference named subDirectories. So your foreach loop will look like this:

```
...
foreach(var directory in directories)
{
 string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.htm");
 DeleteFiles(files);
 var subDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory); 
 DeleteDirectories(directories);
{
....
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Where would I be able to include the additional sub-directories?

Comment: To do that you'll just need to follow asawyer's advice & use the args argument on the Main method. That's the command line argument passed in, so you just list out all of the directories you want to clean as cmd args. You should really read the basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking dumb questions, but can you please be a little more specific, I'm still kind of confused.